# Screenshots not Appearing in Images Folder

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

Screenshots were coming normally in the folder, but then after a while I saw there were no screenshots for almost five days (I take screenshots with keyboard shortcut almost every day).

Answer (score 0):

I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> Which actually copies the screenshot to my clipboard and **does not save it in the Images folder**; but when I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> it was saved in the Images folder but not copied to clipboard.

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with any screenshot shortcut, you can copy it to clipboard and not save it in Images.